# Spyder on Windows Subsystem for Linux - ImportError: libGL.so.1

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu-14.04, anaconda, spyder, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to start Spyder (part of Anaconda) on bash in Windows 10. (It seems to be running Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS.) When typing `spyder &` I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pmj27/anaconda2/bin/spyder", line 6, in <module>
    sys.exit(spyder.app.start.main())
  File "/home/pmj27/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyder/app/start.py", line 103, in main
    from spyder.app import mainwindow
  File "/home/pmj27/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyder/app/mainwindow.py", line 78, in <module>
    from qtpy.compat import from_qvariant
  File "/home/pmj27/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/qtpy/compat.py", line 15, in <module>
    from qtpy.QtWidgets import QFileDialog
  File "/home/pmj27/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/qtpy/QtWidgets.py", line 21, in <module>
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
ImportError: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Does anybody have any experience yet with how to deal with this? I realise that the "Windows Subsystem for Linux" is still in the beta version.

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone else finds this like I did much later, here's what works for me with a similar error message:
I ran `sudo apt-get install qtbase5-dev` (see: https://forum.qiime2.org/t/qiime2-2017-5-installation-on-windows-subsystem-for-linux/694),
installed Xming on Windows (https://sourceforge.net/projects/xming/?source=typ_redirect), and added `export DISPLAY=:0.0` to the end of .bashrc. This resolved the error and I can now run Spyder on WSL.

Comment: can you provide more detail on how to do these? specifically, how would you use Xming and add ```export DISPLAY=:0.0``` at the end of .bashrc

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem, and I have not yet solved it yet. I will try to answer your question as much as my understanding.

I suppose you installed Bash on Ubuntu on Windows as I did. It was mentioned in this link
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/faq
that the Windows Subsystem for Linux is a bash shell that allows developers to use Linux command line tools. When WSL is enabled (it’s an optional feature), the machine downloads a genuine Ubuntu user-mode image, created by Canonical. Bash.exe application, when started, then loads and runs the native Bash shell and Linux command-line tools from the Ubuntu image.

I think it means that your graphic card driver is still on your windows system, so you have to tell your Ubuntu image to access the drive on your Windows. You can access to your windows system in the following directory

> /mnt/c

However not all Linux apps or tools can access a file using /mnt.
A solution is to create a symbolic link.

Windows directory: C:\Users\\Documents\Projects Note: This directory exist.

Linux directory: /home//Projects Note: This directory does not exist.

> ln -s "/mnt/c/Users//Documents/Projects" /home//Projects

Now in WSL you can access the Windows directory as /home//Projects or a specific file as /home//Projects/, and if in WSL the current directory is ~ then Projects/.

source : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/faq

Comment: That is a good thought that had occured to me. To be honest, I had torn the subsystem off again and moved back using good old straightforward Linux rather than messing about with Windows. Did linking against the graphics card drivers solve the problem (You mentioned you didn't manage to solve it yet)? And how did you go about doing so (i.e. what specifically did you link against)? I would have imagined that a graphics card driver for Windows would provide different functions to a Linux one so they might not be compatible.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am using a company computer, and I was denied access to some directories, or write files in the Windows system since I am not the administrator.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am using a company computer, and I was denied access to some directories, or write files since I am not the administrator.(i.e. I can't find the path of libGL on Windows and can't create symbolic link) What's more, Microsoft said WSL does not guarantee support Linux software development with Microsoft software. The purpose of WSL is to let developers use Linux tool to develop Microsoft Apps on Windows 10. I don't think it worth trying. Check the link and read the FAQ.

Comment: That was my impression too which is why I gave up on it. Thank you for sharing what you found out though!